# Understanding FormCollection.AllKeys.Contains

Tags: c#, formcollection

I'm looking at a code block and can't grok what's happening with the line -              `formValues.AllKeys.Contains("Email_" + i);` it looks like an assignment should be taking place but...

```
public ActionResult EditAdditionalLocations(int ID, int? count, FormCollection formValues)
{
    ...

    for (int i = 0; i < _count; i++)
    {
        formValues.AllKeys.Contains("Email_" + i);
        if (locations.Emails.Count > i)
        {
            locations.Emails[i] = formValues["Email_" + i];
        }
        else
        {
            locations.Emails.Add(formValues["Email_" + i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would agree.  It looks like there should be an assignment.  It looks like the `Contains` call is not currently affecting anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that something like this was intended:

```
if (formValues.AllKeys.Contains("Email_" + i)) {
    if (locations.Emails.Count > i)
    {
        locations.Emails[i] = formValues["Email_" + i];
    }
    else
    {
        locations.Emails.Add(formValues["Email_" + i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line checks whether `AllKeys` collection contains `"Email_" + i`, but doesn't do anything with the result.